# Comparing 2 samples - different population

Tags: t-test, assumptions

Is it possible to perform a t-test to explore differences in the means of two datasets with different units?
One dataset contains ecosystem services measures (units: carbon mass, noise reduction,...) and the other dataset, their economical valuation (units: euros)?
I guess it is not possible to do it because they come from different units (populations).

Ranking them all from 0 to 1 makes any sense? Alternative tests? 
Thanks

Comment: Why would you like to compare the means of datasets with different units? This is meaningless. what exactly is it that you want to study here? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: I just was suggested to do so. I want to see if there is any positive relationship between one ecosytem service (e.g. carbon capture) and its economical quantification. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, defining the research question helps. Your question does not include what you are trying to do by comparing 2 samples. Moreover, as far as I understand, you are not comparing 2 samples but you'd like to compare 2 variables of the same sample. So unless you refine your question, I guess you cannot get a definitive answer.

There are many ways of applying t-test but one thing in common is that it assumes t-distribution of the measure. T-distribution is helpful when we don't have large data so that the normal approximation is crude. You can use it to compare means based on your variable, if one of your variables is categorical. If you are comparing two ratio type variables, they basic correlation or regression could help you.

Comment: Thanks: Very explanatory. You are right: I am trying to compare 2 variables of the same sample. One variable refers to economic value, the other refers to ecological value.I need to explore if there is any pattern between the economic and ecological value but I only have one pair of these 2 variables for each type of land use so that I have discarded regression. Thanks so much

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider selecting it as an answer if it is.